# TypeError: 'type' object has no attribute '__getitem__' in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I was trying to analyse the play-by-play data of a basketball team
What I did was to read a csv file into a DataFrame object.

I want to preserve the functionality of the DataFrame object while adding in new attributes to the existing object. Thus I wrote a class called Basketball:

```
from data_math import *
import pandas as pd
class Basketball(pd.DataFrame):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kargs):
        pd.DataFrame.__init__(self,*args,**kargs)
        self.FGM = calculate_FGM(pd.DataFrame)
        self.FGA = calculate_FGA(pd.DateFrame)
        self.FGP = self.FGM / self.FGA
        self.M3  = calculate_3M(pd.DataFrame)
        self.A3  = calcualte_3A(pd.DataFrame)
        self.P3  = self.M3 / self.A3
        self.FTM = calcualte_FTM(pd.DataFrame)
        self.FTA = calculate_FTA(pd.DataFrame)
        self.FTP = self.FTM / self.FTA
    # self.P = score_calculate(pd.DataFrame)
```

I wrote another *data_math.py* file to help calculate the different attributes I wanted to include into the Basketball class.

```
from pandas import DataFrame

def score_calculate(df):
    df_pt_scored = df[((df['etype']=='shot') & (df['result']=='made'))]
    df_ft_scored = df[((df['etype']=='free throw') & (df['result']=='made'))]
    return df_pt_scored['points'].sum()+len(df_ft_scored.index)

def calculate_FGM(df):
    cond_pt = (df['etype']=='shots') & (df['results']=='made')
    cond_ft = (df['etype']=='freethrow') & (df['results']=='made')
    return len(df[cond_pt].index)+len(df[cond_ft].index)

def calculate_FGA(df):
    shot_cond= df['etype']=='shot'
    free_throw_cond = df['etype']=='free throw'
    return len(df[shot_cond].index)+len(df[free_throw_cond].index)

def calculate_3M(df):
    cond_3M= (df['etype']=='shot')&(df['type']=='3pt')&(df['result']=='made')
    return len(df[cond_3M].index)

def calcualte_3A(df):
    cond_3A = (df['etype']=='shot')&(df['type']=='3pt')
    return len(df[cond_3A].index)

def calculate_FTM(df):
    cond_FTM =(df['etype']=='free throw') & (df['result']=='made')
    return len(df[cond_FTM].index)

def calcualte_FTA(df):
    cond_FTA =(df['etype']=='free throw')
    return len(df[cond_FTA].index)
```

In the end I start my program from main.py which I hope would give me the correct output. However while executing on this line:

```
team1= Basketball(tm1)
```

I received the following Traceback

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/luoyicheng/Developer/STAR-Research/data_analysis/source code/main.py", line 20, in <module>
    team1= Basketball(tm1)
  File "/Users/luoyicheng/Developer/STAR-Research/data_analysis/source code/Basketball.py", line 6, in __init__
    self.FGM = calculate_FGM(pd.DataFrame)
  File "/Users/luoyicheng/Developer/STAR-Research/data_analysis/source code/data_math.py", line 9, in calculate_FGM
    cond_pt = (df['etype']=='shots') & (df['results']=='made')
TypeError: 'type' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I am new to python programming and could not figure out why this error has occurred. To my understanding, this error means I am unable to use indexing feature of the DataFrame. However, if I try to code in my main function similar things I am able to get the output I want. I am also not clear of how to extend the existing DataFrame class so that I can still access the methods in the DataFrame class while extending the team1 object to have attributes such as FGM, FGA, etc.

The idea of extending this class is to allow me to pass any DataFrame object in the Basketball() so that I can have an object with extending attributes and methods. I think I also lack an understanding of the use of **init** and self.

Please don't blame for not describing the problem clearly as I am not familiar with all the terminology in OOP.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Please also correct me if I have a poor programming language style. I feel my syntax is inefficient and redundant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing each function `pd.DataFrame` which is of type type:

```
In [11]: type(pd.DataFrame)
Out[11]: type
```

*Hence the exception message.*

You mean to be passing self (which is of type DataFrame):

```
self.FGM = calculate_FGM(pd.DataFrame)
...
```

should read:

```
self.FGM = calculate_FGM(self)
...
```

Comment: Actually I have found typo and it seems working now... By the way how initialize the team1 properly so that I can still preserve the functions that DataFrame offers?

Comment: I'm currently passing the tm1 as a parameter so if I want to access the functions I will have to use tm1.Dataframe.method which I think is redundant

Comment: @ethanluo I don't follow, I also don't see how this can be a typo/be working now. Maybe it's best you ask a separate question, IMO there's too much going on here.

Comment: FTA and 3A the calculate is a typo

Comment: @ethanluo I don't see how that can explain: `TypeError: 'type' object has no attribute '__getitem__'` ...my answer would explain it.

Comment: Perhaps it's the two problems combined. I think the interpreter first identified the error you found. But once I correct it it would return other errors, but now I have had more understanding if the init process so thanks bro